# Word that includes envelope and fax transmission

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a document where I want to say "included in this ______ is a copy of x, y, z." I'm both mailing it and faxing it so I'm not sure what _______ should be. I've considered the words transmission, message, document but am not sure if they are appropriate.

Comment: Correspondence?

Comment: If it's a document, what difference does it make how it's transmitted?

Comment: @deadrat I feel it's misleading if it's a logically separated section on a different page. For example in a package with 10 pages if the first one, being the cover page red, "included in this *document* is a copy of the lease" it may make it sound as if the cover page *was* the document and that the lease was attached to it specifically. Though I may be wrong in this view.

Comment: "Document" is the best of the options you presented, IMO, but any would work. A somewhat similar question was asked before: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218877/general-term-for-content-available-on-web-page-or-as-paper-pdf/218926#218926

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to refer back to the containing message. You can simply say:

> Enclosed are copies of x, y, and z.